# React Fetch download a pdf from Java REST API won't read in Adobe

Tags: reactjs, file, download

I have tested the API in Postman and the PDF renders fine. So I know the API is working correctly.

When I fetch the PDF from within my React code Adobe gives me the error: "Adobe Acrobat cannot open the  because it is neither a supported file type or because the file has been damaged"

The downloaded file is exactly 1kb. So I know the blob isn't being pulled correctly from the API. Is there something I am missing? I've looked at all the examples on the web and I can't seem to find anything wrong.

My React code:

```
const downloadFile = async uploadId => {
    const response = await callFetch("/uploads/download/" + uploadId + "?officerId=" + officerId, "GET", "");
    if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
        alert("Error " + response.status);

        sessionStorage.clear();
        return;
    }

    const file = response.blob();
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob([file], {type:"application/pdf"})
    );

    const filename = response.headers.get("Content-Disposition").split("filename=")[1];

    const link = document.createElement('a');

    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute(
    'download',
    filename,
    );

    // Append to html link element page
    document.body.appendChild(link);

    // Start download
    link.click();

    // Clean up and remove the link
    link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

}; 


const callFetch = (endpoint, method, jsonStr) => {
    let myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    myHeaders.append("Accept","application/json");

    return callFetchApi(endpoint, method, jsonStr, myHeaders);
};

const callFetchApi = (endpoint, method, data, myHeaders) => {
    const serverName = "http://localhost:8080/AuxPolice/api";
    myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", 'true');
    myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');

    const jwt = sessionStorage.getItem("jwt");
    let headerJwt = "Bearer " + jwt;
    if (jwt != null) {
        myHeaders.append("Authorization", headerJwt);
    }



    let myInit = {method: method
                ,headers: myHeaders
    };

    let url = serverName + endpoint;


    if (data) {
        myInit.body = data;
    }

    let returnFetch = fetch(url, myInit);


    return returnFetch;
};
```

Here is my Java code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/download" + "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadGet(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam Long officerId) throws SQLException
{
    Officer loggedInOfficer = this.auxPoliceService.getOfficer(officerId);
    
    
    Upload paramRec = new Upload();
    paramRec.setUploadId(id);

    Upload download = auxPoliceService.getUploads(loggedInOfficer.getOfficerId(), paramRec).get(0);
    
    Blob blob = download.getBlob();
    byte [] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int)blob.length());

    blob.free();

    InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    
    
    String filename = download.getFilename(); 
    String contentType = "application/pdf";

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION);
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + filename);
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .contentLength(bytes.length)
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(contentType))
            .body(resource);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I did attempt that. Adobe will not read it. The file is essentially empty as indicated by the size.

Comment: I opened up the file in Notepad and it's a text file with the content :  [object Response]. However I know the API is working correctly because when I invoke it using Postman , the PDF renders properly. So I'm thinking I'm leaving a step out on the client side in my React.js code. I just don't know what it could be since all the examples I've seen on the internet seem to match my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem!

In my React code I needed to change:

```
const file = response.blob();
```

to

```
const file = await response.blob();
```

Apparently the asynchronous nature of javascript was causing the code to fall though before the blob could be pulled down.

It's working now!